# Charging via air friction in Millikan's oil drop experiment

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, material-science

I am conducting Millikan's oil drop experiment. I use an old leybold setup which is pretty much similar to new one.

The oil drops are charged by air friction. 2 days ago I used to see charged drops much more frequently.

I have searched for a model for air friction but I cannot find anything more than highschool stuff.

Any one know a source that I can find model about charging trough air ressistance so that i can optimize things or any idea to help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: "Some oil drops became electrically charged through friction with the **nozzle** as they were sprayed. Alternatively, charging could be brought about by including an ionising radiation source (such as an X-ray tube). "

Answer (score 1):

the ability to frictionally charge objects with static electricity and have those charges persist in time is strongly affected by the amount of humidity in the air and how much of that humidity then populates the surfaces you are attempting to charge. high humidity tends to make surfaces slightly more conductive, and hence bleed away charges that would otherwise persist on them. this means that if humidity is an uncontrolled variable in your experiment, a test that works one day might not work at all a week later because the humidity changed. best situation for your experiment is the lowest possible ambient humidity.

Comment: Hi,I took more data since I posted the question. The behavior may change in half an hour. I don't think humidity may change in half an hour. Only thing that can change humidity is my breathe which increases humidity I guess.

Comment: Years ago i worked with an engineering buddy on a static electricity generator which used water droplets to transfer charges, i think it was called a Lord Kelvin generator. it was an unstable device; sometimes it worked and other times it stumbled along. so... try not to breathe! ;-)